# Como trabalhar com Json no VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

Observem o código:

[Tabela de endereços](https://jsfiddle.net/wladyband/4pcLfd7L/)

Percebe que a aplicação está funcionando perfeitamente, ao clicar em qualquer endereço ele é automaticamente é direcionado para a página do Google por causa desse método logo abaixo;

```
methods: {
    showLink: function(bancodedado) {
        window.open('http://www.google.com/?q=');

    }
},
```

O que quero fazer é que somente seja direcionado para a pagina do Google quando ele clicar no registro que tiver esse email especifico  `teste111111@google.com.br`

Eu tentei dessa forma, mas não tive sucesso:

```
methods: {
        showLink: function(bancodedado) {
            if (this.bancodedado.email == 'teste111111@google.com.br') {
            window.open('http://www.google.com/?q=');
            }
        }
```

**Como é que eu poderia fazer essa implementação?**

Comment: Tente: `if (bancodedado.email === 'teste111111@google.com.br')`

Comment: Não funciona e ainda dá um erro no console dizendo que a variável email está como indefinida.

Comment: Funciona sim. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/4pcLfd7L/6/

Comment: Cara, funcionou, eu só copiei e colei o código, mas não conseguir encontrar o porque estava dando erro antes, valeu, muito obrigado.   :)

Comment: pode postar essa solução como resposta.    muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Devido o `this`, veja  a [documentação - A Instância Vue](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorre devido o uso do `this`, lembre-se que no contexto de execução global ( Window e ou Document ), o *this* refere-se ao objeto global e quando você cria uma instancia do Vue, é criado um objeto com as propriedades e métodos a ser utilizado pela instancia.

```js
var nome = 'Uma pessoa qualquer',
    idade = 349;

function getPessoa() {
  console.log(this.nome, this.idade);
}
getPessoa();
```

Método de um objeto

```js
var nome = 'Uma pessoa qualquer',
  idade = 349;

function getPessoa() {
  console.log(this.nome, this.idade);
}
getPessoa();

var pessoa = {
  email: 'email@email.com',
  getPessoa: function() {
    console.log(this.nome, this.idade, this.email);
    // undefined
    // undefined
    // email@email.com
  }
}
pessoa.getPessoa();
```

Note que no exemplo acima é criado um objeto com a propriedade **email** e o método **getPessoa** que quando executado o *this* dentro é vinculado ao objeto **pessoa**.

Para melhor entendimento, abaixo links para referência.

- [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [A Instância Vue](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)